# Detecting whether Glassware was launched via voice command or the touch menu

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Is it possible to have different behaviors when a glassware is launched via "OK Glass" voice command vs touch menu selection?
Specifically we are trying to prompt voice recognition if the glassware is launched with "OK Glass" voice command, otherwise go direct to the glassware if it is launched from the touch menu. 
Or, is there a way for an app to know in which way it was launched?
We are trying to emulate what Google Play Music Glassware does.

Comment: What does Google Play Music Glassware do? Do they seem to differentiate the 2 launches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GDK does not yet provide a way to do this. If you would like to see this feature added, please file an enhancement request in [our issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list)!

Comment: Request added: [#426](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=426)

Answer (score 0):

There is no published standard way.  Perhaps you could explore the call stack on entry (e.g. look at what a stacktrace would produce for the different states?